# Please help with question about an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, ideals

Hi I am needing some help and guidance on determining how to know when something is an ideal. We are working with commutative rings.

Our definition of an Ideal I, of a commutative ring R , is a subset of R such that $0 \in I$,

$s,t \in I \to s+t \in I$

and for all $s \in I$, any $r \in R, sr=rs \in I$

I am trying to see if I understand the problem; [image]

My attempt:

For the first one, at first glance both option b and d seem to be candidates. If I had to pick however I would go with b, because it seems to fit all the criteria and doesnt just have a 2 infront of the a. What do you guys think?

Also, I do know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a  principal ideal rings, so maybe that can help to ?

0 is in all of the choices.
All are closed under addition.

(a) wont work because if we multiply by something in our ideal by Z we may not be in ideal.

(b) Seems to work

(c) Doesn't seem to work because $0+a\sqrt{2}$ is in our ideal but this times (c) will give us ab but no root.

(d) I am not as sure. This would be my other choice. Unless im way off, I am between b and d and looking for help

Please everyone my test is tomrrow. I have been trying to know if I am right for over a day . Can anyone please just tell me if I am right by thinking it is b?

Comment: In your definition, are all rings commutative? Otherwise, where you wrote $rs = sr$, that's wrong.

Comment: Yes all commutative thanks

Comment: Just check all of the conditions. Which ones are you getting stuck on?

Comment: You say you've shown your work, but I don't see any work here. To show that a subset is an ideal you need to check certain conditions. Which of those conditions have you checked, which haven't you checked, and what are you getting stuck on when you try to check them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caution:Some authors do not include the ring $R$ among the ideals of $R$..... If $R$  is commutative and has a multiplicative identity $1$, then $1\in I\implies I=R $ because $1\in I\implies I\supset I R=$ $\{i r :i\in I\land r\in R\}\supset \{1 r:r\in R\}=R. $ Also if $R$ is commutative and $x\in I$ where $xy=1$ for some $y, $ then $I=R$ because $1=xy\in \{x r:r\in R\}\subset I.$ For (a) if $Z$ were an ideal of $R=Z[\sqrt 2] $  then $Z=R=Z[\sqrt 2]$ because $1\in Z. $ For (c), if it were an ideal $I, $ then $2=(\sqrt 2)^2\in (\sqrt 2)R=\{\sqrt 2\cdot  r :r\in R\}\subset I R\subset I$ which implies $2=b\sqrt 2$ for some integer $b.$ For (b) (hint) For $u,v \in Z, $we have $u+v\sqrt 2\in I\iff u\equiv 3v \pmod 7.$ For (d) (hint) If $p,q\in Z$ and $(2+3\sqrt 2)(p+q\sqrt 2)=r+s\sqrt 2$ with $r.s\in Z$, then is $s$ necessarily divisible by $3$?

Comment: So then B would be correct?

Comment: HI can you please tell me if it is b or d?